# Why isn't Twitter widget working?

Tags: wordpress, twitter

I have Twitter's own widget set to load on a website, which works just fine.
However, on my WP-powered blog the script is included but not rendered. I call it inside an empty `div` like this:

> ```
> <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/twtr-widget.html' ?>
> ```

But it appears in the page source as HTML (I'm putting '...' to save room):

> ```
> <script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script> 
> <script> 
> new TWTR.Widget({...
> ...</script>
> ```
>
> In other words, the script is not being executed. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot process Javascript with the PHP interpreter - the PHP interpreter will ignore anything which is not bound by `<?php`/`?>` and will simply return the include as part of the document you are serving.

Comment: I thought this to be the case as well, yet putting the Javascript straight into the template yields the exact same result. Any other ideas?

Comment: *@Isaac Lubow* What happens when you load the page with the widget script included? Do you see any Javascript errors?